# Interview Q: Binary tree Inorder traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview.

**Problem:** A **binary tree** and the height of corresponding sub-tree is also given to us. Then we have to find an element at particular position in inorder way.

**For example:** Tree structure is : **D** (Root Node)[subtree-size = 6] --> **B,F**(Child Nodes of D)[subtree-size = 2] --> **A,C,E,G**(leaf nodes)[subtree-size = 0].

So there are total 3 levels: **Level 0**: D; **Level 1**: B,F; **Level 2**: A,C,E,G

We have to **calculate Node at particular order/position in inorder**, say p. if p=2 then node would be B (**inorder traversal**).

**My Solution:** I have suggested that we need to do inorder traversal once(through BFS/DFS) and then we can give the i-th order node and time complexity would be O(n).

Now I was asked that **can I improve the solution based on sub-tree size information**. But I can not come up with any way where sub-tree size can decrease the time complexity.

**Can sub-tree size information reduce the time complexity? If yes then please share algorithm/pseudo code.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we want to find the element at the i-th position in the inorder traversal:

- We know we're looking for the root if the left subtree has exactly `i-1` nodes.
- We know it will be in the left subtree if the left subtree has `i` or more nodes.
- We know it will be in the right subtree if the left subtree has less than `i-1` nodes.
- We can repeat this recursively by updating `i` appropriately. More specifically, we need to decrease `i` by the size of the left subtree plus one whenever we go to the right subtree, as the inorder traversal of that subtree will start at that position of the original inorder traversal. We don't need to change `i` when going to the left subtree, as the inorder traversal of that subtree will start at the starting position of the original inorder traversal.

So, in pseudo-code, we can do the following:

```
currentNode = root
while true
  if getSubtreeCount(currentNode.left) == i-1
    return currentNode
  else if getSubtreeCount(currentNode.left) < i-1
    currentNode = currentNode.left
  else
    currentNode = currentNode.right
    i -= getSubtreeCount(currentNode.left) + 1
```

This will give us a running time of `O(treeHeight)`.

**Example:**

Say we have a tree:

```
     D
   /   \
  B     F
 / \   / \
A   C E   G
```

Say we're looking for the 2nd position in the inorder traversal. We'd start off with D. We'd see that the left subtree has 3 nodes, so we know the 2nd position is in the left subtree. Looking at B, we see the left subtree has 1 node, so we know B is in the 2nd position.

Say we're looking for the 5th position in the inorder traversal. We'd start off with D. We'd see that the left subtree has 3 nodes, so we know the 6th position is in the right subtree. Looking at F, we now look for the 1st position since there's 4 nodes in the inorder traversal before we get to the subtree with F as the root. We see the left subtree has 1 node, so we know that subtree contains the node in the first position. Looking at E, we see the left subtree has 0 nodes, so we know E is in the 1st position in this subtree, i.e. the node we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Dukeling !! But I have few thoughts. 1. O(treeHeight) would be O(n) in worst case as tree has no structure imposed apart from being binary. 2. Again we are doing traversing(can do with DFS/BFS) ,right? Sub-tree size information has not helped much. I might be wrong in my observation, please correct me.

Comment: (1) Indeed `O(treeHeight) = O(n)` if we're talking about any sort of binary tree. But `O(treeHeight) = O(log n)` if it's a balanced binary tree, and, even if it isn't balanced, `treeHeight` is **at worst** `n`, while your suggested solution is **always** O(n). (2) According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), traversing refers to visiting **all** nodes of a tree, while we're not necessarily doing so, by that definition, it doesn't classify as traversal (but it may classify as such by another definition).

Comment: Tree can be balanced and unbalanced and we have to think for worst. :). But even to get a particular element say p=2/i=2, we do not know whether B is at left side/B is at right side(please consider my example). So we have to visit it anyway. Similar logic goes for leaves. Until some order is not imposed on tree structure like binary search, I think we have to traverse. I might sound confused but please help me.

Comment: I am still not convinced that how subtree size can help us nailing down the element in better way. For example: say we have to find element at order 2. Now since root has two tree structure of same size, I get to know that there is left and right sub-trees but still we have to visit left node to get the element at that position, though B and F are the only possible candidate but which one is the right candidate that can only be found by visiting it. Am I right?

Comment: I think that when we use Big O notation then we consider worst case...So when I have used O(n) then I do not mean **always**, but I mean **worst case** (when tree is straight/unbalanced). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As per my high-level algorithm explanation and pseudo-code, we know which side some given index would be on because of the given subtree sizes - we don't need to look further than the child (to get the subtree size) in the wrong subtree.

Comment: You are not wrong in saying that O(treeHeight) is still O(n), but tree height is considered a better (i.e. smaller or equal, but still valid) bound than tree size (n), even though they are the same in the worst case. Just the worst possible case often isn't a particularly useful metric - many algorithms are described by best-, average- and worst-case running times (all in big-O notation). Many algorithms on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) lists all 3.

Comment: The edited explanation is quite enlightening...I think pseudo code need to be updated according to explanation and I think it can be done in O(log n)...

Comment: this is application as in order statistics tree

Comment: @ritesh Are we given the left subtree and right subtree size separately?

Comment: @Sohaib: Every subtree would have size. No mention of left/right subtree.

Comment: @ritesh I dont understand then how the above algo would work as it extensively depends on the numbers of nodes in the left subtree to be i-1

Comment: @Sohaib: Above Algo is not correct. Explanation part in Example is correct. See the Comment by aseem (Order statistics tree) and my comment above that. This question was posed to me in Amazon 1st level Interview. just curious to know that why this question caught your attention? :)

Comment: @ritesh Just like that was browsing through saw this got interested nothing specific. Saw this question on career cup too.